# Prevent pandas from rewriting formatted header to csv for every chunk

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dirty csv with an ugly header that I have formatted and stored in a list.

I want to read this csv chunk by chunk, perform some regex on the data, and then write to a new csv.

I'm using this function to do so

```
def format_data(data_location, formatted_header):
    df = pd.read_csv(data_location, sep=',', skiprows=1,
                     header=0, names=formatted_header, chunksize=10000)

    for chunk in df:
        chunk = chunk.replace('(?!(([^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$),', '', regex=True)
        chunk.to_csv('formatted_data.csv', mode='a', index=False)
```

As I understand what I am doing here:

```
pd.read_csv(data_location, sep=',', skiprows=1,
            header=0, names=formatted_header, chunksize=10000)
```

I am reading the csv from it's location, skipping the first ugly header row and replacing with my formatted_header.

**My issue is that for each new chunk that is written to the new CSV, I am seeing the formatted header row repeated after every 10,000 rows.  How can I prevent this from happening?**

Comment: Can't you just add `header=False` to your `to_csv()` call? `chunk.to_csv('formatted_data.csv', mode='a', index=False, header=False)`

Comment: As pault said, check the documentation about read_csv, header and names are not doing what you think they are doing

Comment: @pault `header=False` gives me no header at all and i want to preserve the header in the first (and only the first) row of the csv that i am writing to

Comment: @OscarD so what are they doing? `Explicitly pass header=0 to be able to replace existing names. `

`Line numbers to skip (0-indexed) or number of lines to skip (int) at the start of the file.`

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question. When you mentioned ugly header it seemed like you wanted to get rid of it and replace it with another one extracted from formatted header. Using 0 will use the first line in the csv as the header, and using skiprows=1 will skip the second one and will not include it at all in your data (as you said, it is 0-indexed). Is it the case that you have a two header row, maybe?. Without showing at least part of your data, we don't have a way to know

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you only want to write the header once, use a boolean to see if you're on the first chunk.

For example:

```
write_header = True
for chunk in df:
    chunk = chunk.replace('(?!(([^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$),', '', regex=True)
    chunk.to_csv('formatted_data.csv', mode='a', index=False, header=write_header)
    write_header = False
```

Comment: this works, but it seems like questionable implementation for `mode='a'`.  neither here nor there, just a comment... Especially not at pault